# My PC is producing a mystery tone on occasion. I think my HDD is beeping?

Tags: hard-disk, hardware

I am using Fedora 38 spin Plasma. I have a Western Digital Blue 1TB HDD that I've been using for some time as bulk storage, though I got it new a couple years ago. Just recently, I started hearing what I analyzed to be a 4054 Hertz tone (yes, it sounds like a pure sine wave) from approximately its part of the case on occasion. Initially, it was only happening sometimes when I opened Discover, then also pretty reliably during system upgrades, and now it's just random. The tone flickers while it's playing, kind of like if an HDD action light was hooked to a buzzer, but it's pretty steady on when it's on, for a good few seconds, and when it's off it's definitely off. It doesn't do sudden tiny chirps, only these like 20 second sessions. I also hear clicking and stuff that sound like HDD. What is this? Is it actually the HDD, or something else? I have never been able to get my motherboard bell to go off, but this noise was happening before I'd even loaded the kernel module for such. If this HDD is dying, I need to know.

Here is the SMART data from Plasma Settings:

```
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.5.7-200.fc38.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD10EZEX-08WN4A0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC6Y1FYNDAT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2be4c19bc
Firmware Version: 02.01A02
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Oct 21 13:16:53 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (12060) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 125) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   182   168   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       1900
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1826
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       16805
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1156
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       261
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       7880
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   112   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     14391         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     14391         -
# 3  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     14391         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     14391         -
# 5  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     12628         -
# 6  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     12628         -
# 7  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     12628         -
# 8  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     12628         -
# 9  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      8698         -
#10  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      8698         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5583         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4237         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3527         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3331         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3251         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2516         -
#17  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      2236         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1665         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1664         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1247         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1030         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

The above only provides legacy SMART information - try 'smartctl -x' for more
```

Comment: um, how does a human determine the tone is 4054 Hz?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - perhaps OP has perfect pitch and he knows the note is about half way between a B7 and C8 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, but not exactly. I just recorded it, and then plotted the spectrum in Audacity. There was a very sharp peak at 4054 Hz, so I generated that tone, and it was the same pitch as the noise.

Comment: @TheLabCat you should've stuck with my story :p I recall spinning rust drives doing that, but they were like full on enterprise drives in a datacentre

Comment: Agreed, Jaromanda's story was good :) No I asked because acoustic measurements for anomaly detection are a pretty standard technique in industrial contexts, so I hoped to find that being introduced in consumer computer hardware without me having noticed it! But: nice diagnostics with audacity!

Comment: I think you should have the `plasma-disks` package installed on the plasma spin. Can you go into the KDE info center and look for "disks" or "SMART" (sorry, not super versed with Plasma/KDE)? Or just install `dnf install smartmontools fpaste` and share the link to the uploaded SMART info that `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | fpaste` gives you? (assuming `sda` is your hard drive in question; omit the `| fpaste` to see what it produces)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had a look when I realized it was probably the HDD, but there were no signs of failure. I’ll post the full data in a bit.